# Keep a user session on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring

I have a Spring MVC web application on which users are able to login and register an account. I am trying to keep a session once a user is logged in and once the user logs out the session is over.

What would be the best way to implement this?

The following is my login controller.

```java
@Controller
public class LoginController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView showLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("login");
        mav.addObject("login", new Login());
        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/loginProcess", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView loginProcess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            @ModelAttribute("login") Login login) {
        ModelAndView mav = null;
        User user = userService.validateUser(login);
        if (null != user) {
            mav = new ModelAndView("loginProcess", "firstname", user.getFirstname());
        } else {
            mav = new ModelAndView("login");
            mav.addObject("message", "Username or Password is wrong!!");
        }
        return mav;
    }
}
```

Comment: use spring-security , dont reinvent the wheel , here some tuts [tutos](https://www.baeldung.com/security-spring) , [spring login form](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends:

1. If you want to "practice" how lower-level stuff works, you could simple call `request.getSession()` to create the session upon login and save something there. Call `session.invalidate()` on logout and you are done.
2. If you feel up for it and want things a bit more streamlined, you could also try and get into [Spring Security](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security) *on top* of your Spring MVC project. Though, it is quite complex to get started if you have no prior experience with it.

Comment: `invalidate()` does not seem to be a method of a HttpServletRequest

Comment: Not of the HttpServletRequest, but of the HttpSession. You can get the session via the request, but need to invalidate the session directly